# Best practice for generating html ids with grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, gsp

I have a template that could be rendered multiple times within the same view.

The template contains a form and I have some jquery event listeners attached to the form elements using the html id.

For now I'm using 'g:set' to create an elementId variable at the top of the template using the current time in milliseconds and appending it to each element on the form. This way each form element will have a unique id within the page no matter how many times the same template is rendered.

My approach works but it seems to me that there must be a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Heres an example of my approach :

```
<g:set var="elementId" value="${'elementId-' + new Date().getTime()}" />

<form>
<g:textField id="${elementId}name" name="name"/>
<g:textField id="${elementId}address" name="address"/>
</form>

<script>
$("#${elementId}name").on("click", myFunction())
$("#${elementId}address").on("click", myFunction())
</script>
```

Comment: Besides my answer, check also your javascript binding, you're missing closing double quotes for the `"click"` event you're binding.

Comment: Sorry..I don't have access to my project at the moment. The syntax is fine there so its just an error in my question. My approach works I just feel like there should probably be a better way of generating ids. Perhaps theres not?

Comment: Misread the question, my bad. Which are the concerns about this approach? It looks decent to me.

Comment: It just felt strange to me to be using time as an id generator. I suppose there could be a small chance of the templates being rendered at the exact same time.

Comment: Travis, if you are really concerned about that then add in a random number to the ID that you generate at the top of the template, or a GUID or UUID.

Answer (score 0):

While it may feel a bit 'odd' or 'strange' to do this, your approach will accomplish what you are after. Adding in a random number or UUID that you generate at the GSP level too would help avoid collisions (though that may be overkill).

Grails doesn't offer any assistance in this manner per say. Since this is a concern of how elements are addressed in the browsers DOM and Grails typically addresses server-side concerns.

The alternative is to refactor your code to not rely upon element ids but rather something more generic and based on classification instead. Using class names would be a good approach. Depending on your requirements this may or may not work well.